# Ef core abstract HasQueryFilter from DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build some generic authorize stuff ontop of DbContext so that my devs do not need to care about authorization in the repos/domain.

Simple example like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property<string>("TenantId").HasField("_tenantId");

    // Configure entity filters
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<string>(b, "TenantId") == _tenantId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
}
```

Which is MS example works.  _tenantId will be used to create an expression and for each instance of DbContext it will use correct value of _tenantId.

But I do not want all our authorizen configured from our DB context, I want to inject it. Something like

```
public class AgreementAuthorization : IEntityAuthorization
{
    private readonly string _legalEntityNumber;

    public AgreementAuthorization(IAuthScope scope)
    {
        _legalEntityNumber = scope.LegalEntityNumber;
    }

    public void Build(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .Entity<Agreement>()
            .HasQueryFilter(a => _legalEntityNumber == null || a.LegalEntity.Number == _legalEntityNumber);
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
   private IEnumerable<IEntityAuthorization> _entityAuthorization;

   MyDbContext(IEnumerable<IEntityAuthorization> entityAuthorization) 
   {
      _entityAuthorization = entityAuthorization;
   }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {                                
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly);

        _entityAuthorization.ForEach(a => a.Build(builder));
    }
}
```

This does not work, query willl test against null every time and pass. If I move the code directly to DbContext it will work. Meaning _entityAuthorization lies directly on DbContext.

Comment: Model configuration happens only once per DbContext type, per AppDomain.

Comment: Thats not the problem, the problem is that the expression cant resolve the member. Same code works when the expression and member is defined on DbContext (Builder still only execute once per app)

Comment: Is your Build() being called?

Comment: yes its called. But when the expression is executed it cant resolve _entityAuthorization member

Comment: Can I somhow build a expression that can resolve the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

> Filters cannot contain references to navigation properties.

You are referencing navigation property `LegalEntity`.

And this could potentially affect you as well as you're passing in an `IEnumerable<IEntityAuthorization>`:

> It is currently not possible to define multiple query filters on the
>   same entity - only the last one will be applied. However, you can
>   define a single filter with multiple conditions using the logical AND
>   operator (&& in C#).

Update:

My guess would then be that you need to reference a field/property of the `MyDbContext` directly and not within another object.  Inject a class/interface that gives access to the values by which to filter then configure the filters at the end of the `OnModelCreating` method.  You can interate over the entity configurations and their properties to apply the desired filter(s) based on the presence of the applicable property.

Comment: I saw that too, funny enough it works just fine when doing the same directly on the DbContext. The problem is in the expresion cant resolve the member used for the query when defined elsewhere. And this is an enterprise level application. Definining things directly on the DbContext will not cut it

Comment: updated; store filter values in fields/properties defined in your `DbContext`

Comment: each implementation of IEntityAuthorization has its own set of data. Defining all on DbContext would bleed dependency

Comment: Well you can have it your way or have it work, @Anders; give it a shot just to see if it works then try do customize it to your liking

Comment: It just won't work in an enterprise scenario, I'll allready abstracted the Set method on the dbcobtext so I'll guess I'll inject my own mechanic there